Are coerced marriages permissible?
What is the fiqh on coerced marriages across the 4 sunni muslim schools of thought? Some questions to consider would be: can a virgin child who is coerced into marriage divorce herself on the basis of the coercion? Can a virgin adult be coerced into a marriage?

According to the following commentator here: islam.stackexchange.com/a/29823/61218; Ibn Battal (al Maliki) said: the majority of the scholars consider forced marriage as invalid قال ابن بطال : ذهب الجمهور إلى بطلان نكاح المكره. So the fatwa i added as a reference you'll find that it is haram for parents to force their daughters to marry somebody they don't want or like. This same ruling is found in the following article here: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/47439/she-was-forced-to-marry-someone-she-did-not-want-can-she-use-contraceptive-pills. What should be made of this discrepancy?

I have also found the following quote to at the very minimum, provide some different insight on the Hanbali position of the matter: –

Ahmad bin Hanbal said, “Her walī should consult her. Then if she grants permission, he can give her in marriage.” I said, “But if she does not grant it?” He said, “If her father is [her walī], and she has not reached seven years of age, then her father’s giving her in marriage is valid, and she has no option. But if she has reached her ninth year, neither her father nor anyone else should give her in marriage without her permission. Chapters on Marriage and Divorce Chapter 3 (Abdullah) §7, translated by Susan Spectorsky –

I'm not trying to debate here, however, it seems to me there are some discrepancies in your answer, and I'd like some extra elaboration on the counter-claims I've just provided.

The quote of Ibn Battal is about males and potentially non-virgin females. Regarding virgin females he has written:
فقالت طائفة: لا يجوز للأب أن ينكح البالغ من بناته بكرا كانت أو ثيبا إلا بإذنها ... وهذا قول الثورى، والأوزاعى، وأبى حنيفة، وأصحابه، وأبى ثور ...  وقالت طائفة: للأب أن يزوج البكر بغير إذنها صغيرة كانت أو كبيرة، ولا يزوج الثيب إلا بإذنها، وهو قول ابن أبى ليلى، ومالك، والليث، والشافعى، وأحمد، وإسحاق،

(A group said: It is not permitted for the father to marry off his adult daughter, regardless of whether she is a virgin or non-vrgin, except when she gives permission ... this is the saying of al-Thawri, al-Awzaa’i, Abu Hanifa and his companions and of Abu Thawr,  ... and a group said: The father may marry off his virgin daughter without her permission, regardless of whether she is a minor or adult, and he may not marry off a non-virgin without her permission, this is the saying of Ibn  Abi Layla, Malik, Al-Layth, Shafi'i, Ahmad and Ishaq)

As for the Hanbalis then there are different sayings of Imam Ahmad on the issue, what I have given is what is adopted as the stance of the Hanbali madhab by most of them.  As for Islamqa it gives answer from the Salafi perspective who tend to follow the opinion of Ibn Taymiyyah who has agreed with the Hanafis.

In an Arabic fatwa they have written: واختلف في البكر البالغ، والراجح اشتراط إذنها ، وهو مذهب أبي حنيفة، خلافا للجمهور (There is disagreement on the marriage of an adult virgin, and what is preferred is that her consent is a condition for he validity of the marriage, which is the madhab of Abu Hanifa as opposed to the majority). You can also find the stance attributed to Maalik and Shafi'i in the english fatwa here

I see, thank you for the clarifications.

Salam and welcome (agaun) to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Further, I strongly recommend that you register and merge your accounts to benefit more from your presence on our site.
